# Solve $e^{e^x}$. How do we solve for $x$ knowing that $e^0=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

Let us take a look at this equation.

$$e^{e^x}=1$$

when $e$ is the base of the natural logarithm.

It may seem intuitive that there are no solutions in any field. After all, $e^0=1$, so there can not be anything $x$ such that $e^x=0$.

Is this true? Are there absolutely no solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Let us take Euler's identity, where $i^2=-1$

$$e^{i\pi}+1=0$$

Subtracting $1$ from both sides, we get

$$e^{i}=-1$$

What happens when we square both sides?

$$e^{i2}=1$$

This means that i2 is *also* a natural logarithm of $1$.

$$e^x=i2$$

Taking the natural log of both sides:

$$x=\ln(i2)=\ln(2)+\ln()+\ln(i)=\ln(2)+\ln()+i/2$$

This is about $1.8379+i1.5708$. It is not yet known if this is transcendental. However, if it is algebraic, then $\ln(2)+\ln()$ (about $1.8379$) must be irrational (and transcendental!).

But wait.

$$(e^{i2})^2=1^2=e^{i4}=1$$

$$(e^{i2})^3=1^3=e^{i6}=1$$

If $z$ is an integer

$$(e^{i2})^z=1^z=e^{i2z}$$

All $i2z$ are natural logarithms of $1$ for all $z$. So the original equation above has the solution set:

$$x=\ln(2z)+\ln()+i/2$$

For all nonzero $z$.

Now let $e=10$. There should be a countable infinitude of solutions.

Comment: Oh no, don't let $e=10$.

Comment: When you "take the natural log of both sides" you are using the complex natural logarithm, which is multivalued. Your conclusion would be correct if you add 2Kπi to one side of the equation, where K can take any integer value.

Comment: To solve for $e=10$, we get

$$10^{10^x}=1$$

Let

$$10^y=1$$

Taking the common logarithm of both sides:

$$y=\log(1)=\frac{\ln(1)}{\ln(10)}=\frac{i2z}{\ln(10)}$$

Substitute, we get

$$10^x=\frac{i2z}{\ln(10)}$$

Again, we take the common logarithm of both sides.

$$x=\log(\frac{i2z}{\ln(10)})=\log(2z)+\log()-\log(\ln(10))+\frac{i}{2\ln(10)}$$

for all nonzero integers $z$

For $z=1$, this is about $0.436+i0.6822$